# How to verify a hashed secret without knowing the salt?

Tags: node.js, typescript, security, bcrypt

I store the API-Keys as hashes in a database.

```js
...
async function createToken(userId:number) {
    ...
    const salt=await bcrypt.genSalt(15)
    const hash=await bcrypt.hash(token, salt)
    await db.store({userId,hash})
}

async function verifyToken(token:string){
    const userId= //I don't know the UserID since only the token is sent as HTTP header
    const hashes= db.get(userId)
    for(const hash of hashes) {
        if(await bcrypt.compare(token, hash)) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

How do I verify the token validity without knowing the `userID`?

The only option I see is to loop through all DB records, and try if the produced hash for that record matches. But this results potentially in thousands of hashes checked before I find the right one.
I may reduce this to only the tokens belonging to a specific UserID. However, this would require my users to also send there userID which I don't want them to do.

Comment: Make userID part of your token. An explicit part, that is easy to extract.

Comment: You can send the salt along with the token. You can even include it with the token eg. using some format like `xxxx.ss` where `xxxx` is the token and `ss` is the salt and the dot separates the token from the salt. The salt is not a secret you need to hide from the end user since that is not the type of attack that salts are designed to prevent. Salts prevents rainbow table attacks which is an attack on the entire database of users instead of a single user.

Comment: However, the traditional solution is to make the user id part of the authentication mechanism. Just like username+password you use user_id+token

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using bcrypt hashes as token to authenticate the users, but that's not the actual purpose of such hashes. If you need to use a token, why not use something like [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token). It can hold the user information, and can be verified without a single db call.